# Зачем нужна коллекция Stack?

Tags: java, коллекции

Зачем нужна коллекция `Stack`, она расширяет `Vector`, который и так уже медленный из-за синхронизации. А в чем прикладной смысл этого `Stack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысл в обратной совместимости. Этот класс (как и Vector) появился еще в 1.0. Сейчас лучше использовать [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

Comment: А разве Deque это не очередь? Стек и очередь это же не одно и то-же....?

Comment: Это двухконцевая очередь. Если игнорировать один из концов, то получается стек.

Comment: Что-то я запутался. Queue это односторонняя очередь - можно получить элементы в том порядке что и добавляли. Deque это двусторонняя очередь - очередь, у которой нет явно выраженного конца и начала. Она может расти и уменьшаться в обоих направлениях. И есть стек - тут можно получить только последний элемент. Правильно?

Comment: Очередь - FIFO. Стек - LIFO. Если у вас вопрос про отличие, то лучше задать его отдельно.